# Reading values from DBML(having stored procedure)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a dbml that has stored procedures dragged off.I have EmployeeModel class that has  get and set propertise .

I have an interface IEmployee and a Repository Employee Repository that has the implementation of the methods.Please refer the code.In Stored procedure GetRoles i just have SELECT * FROM ROLE .

In repository how to loop through the resultset.Can i change ISingleResult to IMultipleResult in dbml designer file?

EmployeeModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcWebsite.Models
{
    public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string TaskMark { get; set; }
        public int RoleFlag { get; set; }
    }
}
```

IEmployee:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MvcWebsite.Models;

namespace MvcWebsite.DAL
{
    public interface IEmployees
    {
        IList<EmployeeModel> ListAll();
        // void Save(EmployeeModel employ);
    }
}
```

EmployeeRepository.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using MvcWebsite.Models;
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace MvcWebsite.DAL
{
    public class EmployeeRepository:IEmployees
    {

        private DataDataContext _dataContext;

        public EmployeeRepository()
        {
            _dataContext = new DataDataContext();
        }


        public IList<EmployeeModel> ListAll()
        {
            //IMultipleResults result =_dataContext.GetRoleDetails();
            //var Emps = result.GetResult(EmployeeModel);
            List<EmployeeModel> emp = _dataContext.GetRoleDetails();
            // foreach (GetRoleDetailsResult role in Emps)
            // {
            // role.Description=Emps.

            // }
            return Emps.ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the resultset as below:

```
        List<EmployeeModel> employeeModels = new List<EmployeeModel>();
        foreach (EmployeeModel employeeModel in _dataContext.GetRoleDetails())
        {
            employeeModels.Add(employeeModel);
        }
```

Or you can use System.Linq.Enumerable class ToList<> method as below:

```
List<Product> products = context.GetProducts().ToList<Product>();
```

IMultipleResults is used when stored procedure is returning more than one result sets. However when you drop such procedures on to the designer, it doesn't generate IMultipleResults. For this you can change the designer generated code to use IMultipleResults as below:

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.FunctionAttribute(Name="dbo.GetCustomerAndProducts")]
[ResultType(typeof(Customer))]
[ResultType(typeof(Product))]
public IMultipleResults GetCustomerAndProducts()
{
    IExecuteResult result = this.ExecuteMethodCall(this, ((MethodInfo)(MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod())));
    return ((IMultipleResults)(result.ReturnValue));
}
```

However, it would overwrite your modifications when you do any changes in the designer because it would regenerate the code. To avoid this you can use partial classes.

Or you can also use SqlMetal tool. It is a command-line tool that generates code and mapping for the LINQ to SQL component of the .NET Framework. This tool generates IMultipleResults.  You can get the details for this tool here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987.aspx

Edited:

Repository functionality will be same regardless of you work in ASP.Net Mvc or WinForms or any other presentation layer.

You can change your repository function to below:

```
public List<EmployeeModel> ListAll()
{
    return _dataContext.GetRoleDetails().ToList<EmployeeModel>();
}
```

Or:

```
public List<EmployeeModel> ListAll()
{
    List<EmployeeModel> employeeModels = new List<EmployeeModel>();
    foreach (EmployeeModel employeeModel in _dataContext.GetRoleDetails())
    {
        employeeModels.Add(employeeModel);
    }

    return employeeModels;
}
```

Comment: If we change designer will it not affect stored procedures.Have u worked on MVC?I am using this code in MVC.

Comment: Yes it will affect the generated code. We will have to move that stored procedure code from generated file to a partial class and will have to remove it from designer. Yes I have.

Comment: Have u worked in MVC?In model i have Employee.cs and dbml,IEmployee and EmployeeRepository in another folder DAL.In EmployeeRepsitory how to return value to list as seen in EmployeeRepsitory.cs.It says "cannot implicitly convert type system.collection.generic.list to system.collection.generic.Ilist".please help......

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the repository function you can create.

Comment: This shouldn't give error. Can you update your question to reflect the IEmployee and EmployeeRepository you have after suggested changes. And also include the exception you receive.

Comment: IEmployee.cs:namespace MvcWebsite.DAL
{
    public interface IEmployees
    {
        IList<EmployeeModel> ListAll();
       // void Save(EmployeeModel employ);
    }
}Then in EmployeeRepository.cs:public IList<EmployeeModel> ListAll()
        {return _dataContext.GetRoleDetails().ToList<EmployeeModel>();}Error :Error 1 Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Linq.ISingleResult<MvcWebsite.DAL.GetRoleDetailsResult>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MvcWebsite.Models.EmployeeModel>' C:\visual studio 2010\Projects\MVC_SP\MvcWebsite\DAL\EmployeeRepository.cs

Comment: Can u send me some sample MVC project using dbml with stored procedures(using aspx) to my email id:guhananth@gmail.com